# Ant design - How to detach form item name from field value

Tags: javascript, frontend, antd

I have a very simple question, can't find the answer in the official documentation. I want to get data for my form item from a specific nested object, but the name should be different. Is it possible to do without mapping in an `onFinish` hook?

I have the following form item

```
<Form.Item
    label="Place"
    name={["place", "id"]}
    rules={[{required: true}]}
>
    <Select {...placeSelectProps}  />
</Form.Item>
```

Is it possible to get value from `place.id` but change the name to `placeID`?

I tried to use `fieldKey`, but it doesn't work:

```
<Form.Item
    label="Place"
    name="placeID"
    fieldKey={["place", "id"]}
    rules={[{required: true}]}
>
    <Select {...placeSelectProps}  />
</Form.Item>
```